# How to query DB table with additional fields from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a HN-style database, and I'm trying to query a list of 'posts', that contain a 'userHasVoted' property for each one (this checks to see if the user currently logged in has voted for that specific post). (Note: the `userHasVoted` field does not exist - but needs to be dynamically created if the user has voted for a specific post.)

The 'posts' live in a separate table as the 'votes', joined on `post.id` and `votes.postId`.

How can I query the DB to show *every* post with this property, not limited to just the posts the user has voted for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking, but I think the most likely scenario is you used an `INNER JOIN` (perhaps expressed as just `JOIN`), which will only return results where a record from both tables actually exists. What you want is an **outer join**, which will let you keep records from the first table if no record matches in the second:

```
SELECT p.*, case when v.postid is not null then 1 else 0 end as UserHasVoted
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.postid = p.id and v.userid = @UserID
```

Comment: Ah, `CASE WHEN`... that's what I was looking for. Thanks!